# How to ignore find() errors

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Again, I'm new to python, but in other languages error handling is easy. I'm not sure how to do this in python.  The **temperature** variable on the web page doesn't hold a value for the 1st item in the list, but the other items have it.  How do I ignore an item is it doesn't return something back.  I want it to continue with the other code and skip the list that doesn't have a class.

### Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=28.57117500000004&lon=-81.38776499999994#.YHH8fehKiUk')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-body')

items=week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')

period_names = [item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]

short_descriptions = [item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]

temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]

print(period_names)
print(short_descriptions)
print(temperatures)
```

### Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Youtube_posting.py",
> line 12, in 
> temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]   File
> "c:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Youtube_posting.py",
> line 12, in 
> temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use a try/except clause and catch the AttributeError exception and pass on it.

```py
try:
    temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

This will do exactly what you asked, which is ignore an item if `item.find(class_='temp')` returned a `NoneType` and move on to the next item.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the element with `class="temp"` exists in item and if not, return a default value (e.g `"N/A"`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=28.57117500000004&lon=-81.38776499999994#.YHH8fehKiUk"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

week = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast-body")
items = week.find_all(class_="tombstone-container")
period_names = [
    item.find(class_="period-name").get_text(separator=" ") for item in items
]
short_descriptions = [
    item.find(class_="short-desc").get_text(separator=" ") for item in items
]
temperatures = [
    i.get_text(separator=" ") if (i := item.find(class_="temp")) else "N/A"
    for item in items
]

for p, d, t in zip(period_names, short_descriptions, temperatures):
    print("{:<30} {:<40} {}".format(p, d, t))
```

Prints:

```
NOW until 7:00pm Sat           Red Flag Warning                         N/A
This Afternoon                 Chance T-storms                          High: 90 °F
Tonight                        Showers Likely then Chance Showers       Low: 69 °F
Sunday                         Heavy Rain                               High: 79 °F
Sunday Night                   Chance Showers                           Low: 67 °F
Monday                         Mostly Sunny                             High: 86 °F
Monday Night                   Mostly Clear                             Low: 62 °F
Tuesday                        Sunny                                    High: 87 °F
Tuesday Night                  Partly Cloudy                            Low: 65 °F
```